# Trying to update my location even if app is closed

Tags: android, android-studio, location

I am building an app that tracks people location, and I use work manager to update  my database on the current user location.
Now I understand that it won't work when the app is closed, so what can I do if I want the app to always update my last location to my database?
Is there any another way to do this instead of using the work manager? And what is more efficient?
This is my work manager:

```
        Constraints constraints = new Constraints.Builder()
                .setRequiresBatteryNotLow(true)
                .build();

        PeriodicWorkRequest uploadWorkRequest = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(UpdateWorker.class, 15, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .setConstraints(constraints)
                .build();

        WorkManager.getInstance(MapsActivity.this).enqueue(uploadWorkRequest);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a Bound Service
[image]

There is very detailed demo code in the android site here:
[developer.android.com bound-services explanation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services#Lifecycle)

Comment: I forgot to say that if you want to leave this permanently on background you need to start a service by calling startService() which allows the service to run indefinitely, and you can also allow a client to bind to the service by calling bindService()